# ValueError: could not convert string to float - without positional indication

Tags: python, csv

For a current project, I am planning to run a scikit-learn Stochastic Graduent Booster algorithm over a CSV set that includes numerical data.

When calling line `sgbr.fit(X_train, y_train)` of the script, I am however receiving a `ValueError: could not convert string to float:` with no further details given on the respective area that cannot be formatted.

I assume that this error is not related to the Python code itself but rather the CSV input. I have however already checked the CSV file to confirm all sections exclusively include floats:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why the `ValueError` is appearing without further positional indication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing there are not direct function to get positional indication.
you can try this to convert

```
   print (df)
       column
    0  01
    1  02
    2  03
    3  04
    4  05
    5  LS

print (pd.to_numeric(df.column.str, errors='coerce'))
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    5.0
5    NaN
Name: column, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for the good input. I tried this approach but am receiving the error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numeric'`. Could the string to float issue be related to the fact that I am using `fillna("")` in the code?

Comment: In fact to_numeric is not a attribute of dataframe but it is an attribute of pandas package.
You should have a function with entry numeric value and output other numeric value (float) but you give in place of numeric value a dataframe

Comment: Got it and you are right - this solved things. One quick final point: the code is yielding the error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'` - what exeactly would you use for `column` to make to comply with the CSV dataset?

Comment: It is columns not column

Comment: BigG, you still have `column`, not `columns`.  Also I don't get a Series with this, but rather a single element array.  You answer has given rise to another error.

Comment: Here (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) You can get the list of attribute of dataframe class.
It is good, columns give an array not series. you can convert it to series. 
explain your error,